# How to fetch xml file data to grid in mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a mvc application which contain on grid view, that contains the data of the xml file, so I need to read xml file data and display that data in grid using mvc

Comment: Have a look at my answer. Hope it will help you to solve your problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot write code for that. But I can suggest you that use `XMLSerialization` and map all XML data to `Property Class` and pass object of that property class to view as a model.

And in your view you can simply use all properties of that model.

**References:**

1. [How to serialize and deserialize XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483055/XML-Serialization-and-Deserialization-Part)
2. [List Model Binding in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/766214/List-Model-Binding-in-MVC)